# Parse nsmutabledictionary store user telephone numbers in an array

Tags: iphone, ios, nsarray, nsdictionary

I am new to iphone development.I am developing an app in this i want to parse this dictionary and store the telephone numbers in an array.Can any one help..
thanx in advance.Here is the code i tried.

```
-(void)filterContacts{
NSLog(@"I am here");
NSArray *letters = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"A", @"B", @"C", @"D", @"E", @"F", @"G", @"H", @"I", @"J", @"K", @"L", @"M", @"N", @"O", @"P", @"Q", @"R", @"S", @"T", @"U", @"V", @"W", @"X", @"Y", @"Z", nil];
NSMutableArray* test=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSMutableArray* obj=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSLog(@" Data %@", dataArray);

  for (int i=0; i<arrayLetters.count; i++) {
        [test addObject:[[dataArray objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:[arrayLetters objectAtIndex:i]]];
}
for (NSDictionary *dict2 in test) {

    NSLog(@"%@",[dict2 valueForKey:@"telephone"]);
}

}
```

When i print this array i am getting null.The data which i have to parse is shown below.

```
2012-12-03 20:08:29.314(
  )

 2012-12-03 20:08:29.315  (
"1 (234) 560-789,20313561301"
  )

 2012-12-03 20:08:29.316  (
   "(000) 000-0000"
  )


DataArray (
    {
    "#" =         (
    );
    A =         (
    );
    B =         (
    );
    C =         (
    );
    D =         (
    );
    E =         (
    );
    F =         (
    );
    G =         (
    );
    H =         (
    );
    I =         (
    );
    J =         (
    );
    K =         (
                    {
            letter = K;
            name = kkkkkk;
            rowSelected = "-1";
            telephone = "1 (234) 560-789,20313561301";
            telephoneSelected = "";
        }
    );
    L =         (
    );
    M =         (
    );
    N =         (
    );
    O =         (
    );
    P =         (
    );
    Q =         (
    );
    R =         (
                    {
            letter = R;
            name = RRRRR;
            rowSelected = "-1";
            telephone = "1234567890";
            telephoneSelected = "1234567890";
        }
    );
    S =         (
    );
    T =         (
    );
    U =         (
    );
    V =         (
    );
    W =         (
    );
    X =         (
    );
    Y =         (
    );
    Z =         (
    );
}

)
```

Comment: I love that array initialization... soooo compact.

Comment: H2CO3@: give some idea to solve this issue

Comment: you can use a for loop for doing it more concisely.

Comment: i tried for last two days i am strugggling

Comment: if you are getting the telephone no     *** 2012-12-03 20:08:29.315  (
"1 (234) 560-789,20313561301"
  )*** then what is the problem

Comment: i want to store in that values in an array

Comment: Still this issue is not solved any one pls help me...

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in your loop:

```
for (NSDictionary *dict in dataArray) {
    [test addObject:[[dataArray objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:[arrayLetters objectAtIndex:i]]];
    [obj addObject: [[dataArray objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"telephone"]];
}
```

Notice how you are iterating over NSDictionary, yet nowhere in your loop do you actually refer to your loop variable. The first line should refer to dict, and the second just looks wrong because you are trying to index into a dictionary value rather than a dictionary proper.  Try this:

```
for (NSDictionary *dict in dataArray) {
    [test addObject:dict valueForKey:[arrayLetters objectAtIndex:i]]];
    [obj addObject:[dataArray valueForKey:@"telephone"]];
}
```

Again, I'm making some assumptions here in the absence of information in your post. Your original post was missing some things like details on the format of dataArray (I assume your data sample is supposed to be the contents of dataArray, but it would help to explicitly say this) and what arrayLetters was supposed to be.  Therefore, there may be other problems with your code; if the above doesn't resolve your issue, please edit your post to include that information.

Comment: Then please edit your post to show your new code.  Your code currently shows you not using dict.  We need one version of the code if we are to help you.  If you intend not to use dict, please explain it, because it looks like a bug.

Comment: I don't see a change.  It still has you using [dataArray objectAtIndex:0] instead of dict insider your inner loop.

Comment: I edited my answer to show what I think the inner loop should look like.  Please try that.  Also try what some of the other answers recommend and see what works.  If nothing works, please edit your original post to show more details.

Comment: array letter refers to alphabets, where respone is the data array which i have to parse

Answer (score 0):

You are not parsing the dictionary properly as per details you provided i have modified your code. check that.

```
-(void)filterContacts{
NSLog(@"I am here");
NSMutableArray* test=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSMutableArray* obj=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSLog(@" Data %@", dataArray);

for (int i=0; i<arrayLetters.count; i++) {
    for (NSDictionary *dict in dataArray) {
        [test addObject:[dict valueForKey:[arrayLetters objectAtIndex:i]]];
         if([test objectAtIndex:0]!= nil){
              [obj addObject: [[[dict valueForKey:[arrayLetters objectAtIndex:i]] objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"telephone"]];
           }

}
   // NSLog(@" My test %@", obj);

}
```

**Edit**

```
-(void)filterContacts{
NSLog(@"I am here");
NSArray *letters = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"A", @"B", @"C", @"D", @"E", @"F", @"G", @"H", @"I", @"J", @"K", @"L", @"M", @"N", @"O", @"P", @"Q", @"R", @"S", @"T", @"U", @"V", @"W", @"X", @"Y", @"Z", nil];
NSMutableArray* test=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSMutableArray* obj=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSLog(@" Data %@", dataArray);

  for (int i=0; i<arrayLetters.count; i++) {
        [test addObject:[[dataArray objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:[arrayLetters objectAtIndex:i]]];
}
for (NSDictionary *dict2 in test) {

    NSLog(@"%@",[[dict2 objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"telephone"]);
}

}
```

In dict2 the value will be

```
( 
                {
        letter = K;
        name = kkkkkk;
        rowSelected = "-1";
        telephone = "1 (234) 560-789,20313561301";
        telephoneSelected = "";
    }
);
```

so you should show `objectAtIndex:0` to identify the `telephone` key in dictionary.
`Note check for the character "K" or "R" only coz all other character values are empty`

Comment: I am getting only null value now also

Comment: I have tried this code but i am getting obj (
        (
    ),
        (
    ),
        (
    ),
        (
    ),
        (
    ),
        (
    ),
        (
    ),
        (
    ),
        (
    ),
        (
    ),
        (
    ),
        (
    ),
        (
    ),
        (
    ),
        (
    ),
        (
    ),
        (
    ),
        (
    ),
        (
    ),
        (
    ),
        (
    )
)

Comment: i want array in the format  ('1234567890','2012341301','1234567990')

Comment: Do you get output with this answer???? you can add the output to the array using addObject method to obj

Comment: this is same code i already written i want in the format i mentioned